# htaccess rewrite sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bluehost

I have a production copy and a test copy of my website on bluehost.  Each website is in it's own directory in public_html folder, one named prod another named test.  According to bluehost knoweldge base here: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347 you setup an htaccess file to rewrite requests coming into the public_html folder to my prod folder.  This works pretty well thus far.  Something I noticed recently though was with these rewrite settings that if you attempt to load a website file from another directory inside the main website folder e.g. /prod/testfolder without a forward slash on the end it will redirect you to www.mysite.com/prod/testfolder/ instead of staying on www.mysite.com/testfolder.  This condition does not happen if you specify the extra forward slash like so.... www.mysite.com/testfolder/

Here is my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prod/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prod/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ prod/index.php [L]
```

I'm not an expert when it comes to rewriting urls using htaccess however I suspect the first chunk of rewrite rules is the cause of this.  BTW an example of why this makes a difference is that I setup a blog on this site and if you attempt to visit the blog at www.mysite.com/blog it redirects to www.mysite.com/prod/blog/ which defeats the purpose of using htaccess to mask the prod folder in the first place.  Can anyone tell me how I should go about fixing this and maybe explain why it's happening?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to withdraw my answer because it has nothing to do with your actual problem.